# Is cl-http still usable and how to install it

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

How to install fantastic beast (CL-HTTP) on SBCL (or ccl) if it is still usable and why people are not using it anymore (extra question)?

Comment: The web site http://cl-http.org/ seems to be down for at least the last two days, I assume that's not a good sign. The wikipedia article mentions a proprietary license, maybe that's a reason why it is not used widely. Hunchentoot should be an alternativ which can be installed easily using quicklisp.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is an old lisp project. You can find the sources and the binaries [here](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/cl-http/cl-http.html). Since is written in Common Lisp it should work (maybe with some changes) in modern implementations (last release is from 2003), and probably modify the way that the system is build with ASDF

This is a good project for learning, but if you want to make web development with common lisp I recommend you to use first Quicklisp, for installing the libraries and take a look here for web frameworks or servers:

http://quickdocs.org/search?q=web

I also recommend that take a look to:

- https://github.com/edicl/hunchentoot (as suggested in a comment by @Martin Buchmann and is an http server)
- https://shirakumo.github.io/radiance/ (this is my favorite, have a nice tutorial)
- https://github.com/fukamachi/caveman (all the things comming from Fukamachi are really great common lisp tools)
- https://github.com/skypher/weblocks (old but still mantained)

Comment: I am developing web apps for sometime and keep looking for good building blocks. I have tried all these [mentioned above] but cl-http is something else.

Comment: A new version of Weblocks is being worked on and it has a new nice and easy [quickstart](http://40ants.com/weblocks/quickstart.html) ! I also recommend the [awesome-cl#network-internet](https://github.com/CodyReichert/awesome-cl#network-and-internet) list. I personally enjoyed better [Snooze](https://github.com/joaotavora/snooze) than Caveman (for handling of parameters and ease of debugging built-in).